# Not able to set retryDelayOptions in AWS lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am trying to set customBackOff function to keep track of my Kinesis lambda function.
Below is a code snippet.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
  retryDelayOptions: {
    customBackoff: function(retryCount) {
      console.info('Within Retry.. ' + retryCount);
      return 100;
    }
  }
});
```

As per aws documentation Lambda service supports customBackoffFuction.

Links

[AWS lambda class](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html)

[AWS config class](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html#retryDelayOptions-property)

in aws-sdk source code I don't see retryDealayOptions property. Can you please suggest am I missing anything here while setting up retry policy in lambda function.

AWS SDK fails to set this property.
Following code returns undefined value for retryDelayOption as key is missing in Config.js

```
console.log(AWS.config.retryDelayOption);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `retryDelayOption` is a new feature for the Javascript SDK, added in aws-sdk@2.2.35 (February 11, 2016), but not yet deployed in Lambda by default.  From a quick check experiment, Lambda has aws-sdk@2.2.32 (January 22, 2016).

You would have to bundle and upload a more recent SDK with your Lambda to make that work until Lambda is updated to 2.2.35, probably in a month or so.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are missing **`s`**
   `console.log(AWS.config.retryDelayOption` **`s`** `);`

`AWS lambda class` is used for managing your lambdas like you do in AWS Console. Also you can run lambdas like this with it. But I assume it's not what are you trying to do.
Likely you are trying to write something to DynamoDB inside of your Lambda and your `customBackoff` is not firing.
From [AWS config class](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html#retryDelayOptions-property)
`Note: This works with all services except DynamoDB.`
For some reason they [hardcoded retry logic for DynamoDB](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/lib/services/dynamodb.js#L49-L52)

General advice in this case would be using `maxRetries` for your DynamoDB constructor.

```
var dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB({maxRetries: 8});
```

I found that `maxRetries: 8` works best for my lambdas. Giving it about `7 sec` for all retries. Which perfectly fits into my `10 sec` lambda timeout

Answer (score 0):

```
aws.config.update({region:'eu-west-1',maxRetries:0,retryDelayOptions:{base:10000}});
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html

Comment: Your answer should explain in detail why and how it solves the problem.  Also, please post relevant information from links directly into your answer.